# Trouble finding the interval to integrate over: $P(X+1< Y)$

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

In a task i get the following density function: $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=6e^{-3x}e^{-2y}$ if  $\ 0\ < x \ < \infty$ and $\ 0 < y < \infty$.

I'm asked to calculate: $P(X+1< Y)$ and this was my first try:

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^{y-1}6e^{-3x}e^{-2y} dxdy =1-\frac{2e^3}{5}$$ which is wrong.

Second try:
$$\int_0^\infty \int_{x+1}^\infty6e^{-3x}e^{-2y} dydx=\frac{3e^2}{5}$$ which is correct.

Every time I get a task like this, it is done wrong. Can explain to me, how I should choose the correct interval, please?

Comment: I will give you a hint: you have $1<X+1<Y$. And now recheck the first integral. Let me know if you don't see it.

Comment: I still got a little trouble understanding it. Can you explain a little bit further, Shashi?

Comment: In your 'first try', the upper limit for the $x$ integral should be $\max(y-1,0)$.

Comment: Okay, you integrate the density over the region $x+1<y$. The density is nonzero for $x, y>0$, so you better integrate over the region where it is nonzero. Solving $x+1<y $ and $x, y>0$ yields: $1<y$ and $0<x<y-1$. Hence the integral must be: $$\int^\infty_1\int^{y-1}_0... dx\, dy$$Now clear?